# Problem setting HorizontalAligment="Stretch" in ListBox's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want my items in listBox to stretch horizontally, but if item's content is bigger than listbox then horizontal scrollbar appears. How to avoid this?

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="testTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="border" 
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    Margin="2" 
                    Padding="2" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource testTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled`:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    ...
</ListBox>
```